# Class has not initializer in Swift

Tags: swift

I am getting the following error, I wonder why it requires to have initializer and how to handle it?

> Class 'MasterViewController' has no initializers

```
struct FullOrderData :Codable
{
    let meta :meta
    let links : links
    let data :[OrderData]
}

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

   var fullOrder : FullOrderData

}
```

Comment: If your class has no initializers, it can't be initialized. Simple as that, you have no way of using an object, if you didn't define a way for such an object to ever be created in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a custom initializer `init` like this:

```swift
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

   var fullOrder : FullOrderData

    init(fullOrder: FullOrderData) {
        self.fullOrder = fullOrder
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        fullOrder = // a default value for `fullOrder` or make fullOrder optinal
    }
}
```

If you plan on making `fullOrder` optional you won't require to make a custom initializer since the compiler assumes `nil` for `fullOrder` during initialization.

Comment: I am now getting `Thread 1: Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented`

Comment: @casillas If you are using story-board you need to implement `init(coder:)` too. I've updated my answer check now.